# How do KTables interact with Kafka on startup?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm a little confused on how this works conceptually.

How does kafka streams guarantee that the partitions assigned to it from the kafka broker match the partitions assigned for other topics? Seems like there needs to be some coordination happening?
Also, does kafka streams always read the compacted topic from the beginning, or does it read from latest offset? Once it reads the messages from the compacted topic, does it commit the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does kafka streams guarantee that the partitions assigned to it
> from the kafka broker match the partitions assigned for other topics?

Kafka streams application subscribes to one or more topics under an `application.id` which resembles `group.id` in Kafka-clients.

When a client requests Kafka broker for subscription of a topic with a particular `group.id` it returns a set of partitions for that topic.
If all the topics partitions are assigned to any streams instance under the same `application.id`, a re-balance will be triggered and the newly started streams instance will receive its share of the partitions and the old instance will no longer be listening to those partitions.

> Does kafka streams always read the compacted topic from the beginning,
> or does it read from latest offset?

Whether compacted or otherwise, Kafka streams applications reads from the last committed offset.

> Once it reads the messages from the compacted topic, does it commit
> the offset?

From the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management#KafkaStreamsInternalDataManagement-Commits), it is stated that..

> Kafka Streams commit the current processing progress in regular
> intervals (parameter commit.interval.ms). If a commit is triggered,
> all state stores need to flush data to disk, i.e., all internal topics
> needs to get flushed to Kafka. Furthermore, all user topics get
> flushed, too. Finally, all current topic offsets are committed to
> Kafka. In case of failure and restart, the application can resume
> processing from its last commit point (providing at-least-once
> processing guarantees).

While writing a Kafka streams application, the developer need not manually take care of committing the offsets because it is internally done by Kafka streams.

Comment: With regard to partitions, my thinking is that in order for kafka streams to support joins in a partitioned environment, it would need to get the SAME partition for each topic (in order to perform joins etc). I.e. It needs to know that it will get the same keys values to join on. I was wondering what the rules are around that?
With regard to offsets, what happens if your client application is torn down and recreated? I.e. there is no backing data? I can only assume that it would need to use a new group ID in that case in order to fetch data from the beginning?

Comment: @Darren Yes, if the no. of partitions are same for both the topics you want to join on, then the same partition will be chosen for joins i.e. partition 0 of topicA and partition 0 of topicB gets assigned to the same instance. You will also need to ensure that the partitioning logic is also same, so partition 0 of both the topics contain the same set of keys